# show slave status \G into outfile '/tmp/slavestatus.txt';

Tags: mysql, bash

Is it possible to write to outfile with the mysql command "show slave status;"?

I have over 20 servers, and I'm writing a bash script to check the replication on all of them. I need to output all of the data into one file on my local server.

This is what I have so far, but I can't figure out how to pipe the data into a file I can run regular expressions on.

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((server=8100; server <= 8121; server++)); do
        ssh pos$server <<-ENDEXP
                mysql -u root -p12345 pos_master_prod
                show slave status \G
                \q
        ENDEXP
done
```

Comment: Why not setup nagios for monitoring mysql replication? It is an excellent tool and you can find a lot of resources online to monitor replication and output data in many standard formats.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirements as you have and ended up using [tee](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee). Basically it´s @Chandranshu setup, but using tee to pipe data into a file.

```
mysql -u root -p'rootpw' pos_master_prod 'show slave status \G' | tee slavestatus.log
```

Tee was installed by default on my ubuntu boxes, otherwise you can ofcourse get it from a repository like apt-get or yum.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to run a mysql query from the command prompt is to use the -e option. Hence this would work:

```
ssh pos$server "mysql -u root -p12345 pos_master_prod -e 'show slave status \G'" >> output.log
```

UPDATE: About the "into outfile" part, it is not allowed in the syntax. Trying "show slave status into outfile 'xxx'" on the mysql prompt will result in the following error:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'into outfile "xxx"' at line 1